# Adding effect to ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qr2iqU4hJvZiOn85dQjv?p=preview) I have an `ngTable` with four rows. When the user clicks the button below the table, I need the background color (not the text) of the second row to fade in and fade out. The row gets colored in fade in, however after two seconds the background color suddenly disappears instead of fading out. Any ideas how to fix this?

CSS

```
.select {
  transition: 1s linear all;  
  opacity: 1;
}

.select.ng-hide {
  transition: 1s linear all; 
  opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in data" ng-class="{ 'select': u.select}">
                <td title="'User ID'" style="width:150px">{{ u.uid }}</td>
                <td title="'Name'" style="width:150px">{{ u.nm }}</td>
                <td title="'Group'" style="width:200px">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="selectRow()">Color second line and fade</button>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$timeout,NgTableParams) {


    $scope.data = [ 
      { uid: 'User 11', nm: 'Name 11', ugr: 'Group 1'},
      { uid: 'User 12', nm: 'Name 12', ugr: 'Group 1'},
      { uid: 'User 21', nm: 'Name 21', ugr: 'Group 1'},
      { uid: 'User 22', nm: 'Name 22', ugr: 'Group 1'}
    ];

    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({dataset: $scope.data});

    $scope.selectRow = function(){
      $scope.data[1].select = true;
      $timeout(function(){
          $scope.data[1].select = false;
      },2000);
    };

});
```

Comment: what is the expectation? you want the fade out to be slow ?

Comment: yes, the background color should fade in and out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another css to unselect the row

```
.unselect {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 1s linear all; 

}
```

then put ternary operator in your ng-class

```
ng-class="{true: 'select', false: 'unselect'}[u.select]"
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mMD180zpdrfviDsS4KYt?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You should have your styles as below,

```
.select {

  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: opacity 2s;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.select.ng-hide {

   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: opacity 2s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**Reason:** To see in chrome you need

1. -webkit-transition
2. you had `opacity:1` for .select which changes the opacity next second when timeout happens.

**[UPDATED PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/KlpC90TfOV8RYRedvZqu?p=preview)**

Comment: this works with the background, however the text disappears on fade out and it should not.

Comment: Sorry, but now the background just appears and disappears, there's no fade in or fade out.

Comment: Lets continue in [discussion chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137274/adding-effect-to-ngtable)

Comment: @ps0604 I shall change it to initial version itself. I updated the plunk to your expected version

Comment: Sorry, but the background has to fade in/out gradually

Comment: what else is happening?